# Getting following Error in javascript code : Do not use 'new' for side effects

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, vue-component

[image]I have a vuejs code with which I try to represent in a bar chart the percentage of water and oil contained in two different bottles.
when i start my program, i get the following error in my javascript code:

Do not use 'new' for side effects (no-new) at src\mixins\charts\BalkenChart.js:15:9:
I don't quite understand what this error refers to. Could someone help me

```
import Chart from 'chart.js'

export default {
name: 'Chart',
props: {
    oil: Number,
    water: Number
},
mounted() {
    this.renderChart()
},
methods: {
    renderChart() {
        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['Oil', 'Water'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Percentage',
                    data: [this.oil, this.water],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
}
```

In Vue component, I have the following code

```
  <template>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart" ref="chart"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>



<scipt>
import Chart from '@/components/Chart'

export default {
  components: {
    Chart
  },
  data () {
    return {
      oil: 30,
      water: 70
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$refs.chart.renderChart()
  }
}
</script>
```

to solve the problem I assign a variable to the result just like that, but I got the error, myChart ist assigned but never use.

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...} )
```

Comment: If you google "eslint no-new" you get a whole page explaining what that option does.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `new` is to create an object from a *Class* or *constructor function*.

If you never do anything with the resulting object, then what's the point of creating that object?

Clearly *something* is happening, but that's a side-effect and not what `new` is designed for. Your linter is objecting.

If you assign to a variable that you never use, then you have the same issue just one step removed.

---

If we assume that the object is useless, then the ideal solution is to rewrite your `Chart` function so that it doesn't need `new` to work.

It might also be the case that the object created has methods which are useful in other circumstances, but in this particular bit of code aren't needed. In that case, it might be appropriate to disable the rule in your linter.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-new
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
```

Comment: ChartJS attaches the created object to the DOM element (the `<canvas>`), so the code does make sense. (At least I think it does; it's been a few years since I used it.)

Comment: @Pointy — That's a side effect that doesn't need `new`

Comment: well yea, I'm not a ChartJS contributor so I won't comment on the architecture. That's what all their sample code does however.